# Unable to access nested JSON fields stored in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

The objective I want to complete is to perform a 'count' on the # of times any number has appeared within the column 'mjtheme_namecode'. My tutor has said we **must** use the json_normalize method to complete this task.

Normally I would use pd.value_counts() but there is additional text in the cell so this isn't possible.

The format is below:

[image]

I have used pd.read_json to read the data into a pandas dataframe and then filtered on the column mjtheme_namecode. I have tried accessing the data using json_normalize as per below but I continue to get an error stating: "string indices must be integers".

```
sample = df.to_json #Convert series to a json string
json_normalize(sample2, 'name')
```

Could anyone point out how I can potentially resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is possible create some small sample of json file? First idea - `json_normalize(sample2, 'mjtheme_namecode')`, but untested because no json sample.

Comment: Definitely. Please find a link attached:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yFbjt9HiEvAxm3DWArBK53oPINIaTA3S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('world_bank_projects.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(data, 'mjtheme_namecode')
print (df.head())
  code                                   name
0    8                      Human development
1   11                                       
2    1                    Economic management
3    6  Social protection and risk management
4    5                  Trade and integration
```

Comment: How peculiar...I will have to refresh and re-attempt this again! I will let you know if I receive the same answer as yours or another. Thank you.